# VSTS - How to transfer/move my work (source code) from Master page to a new branch

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tfs, azure-devops

I accidentally started working from master page weeks ago, made some development already since 2 weeks, and just realized that now.

So How would I create a new branch in VSTS and move my work in the new created branch?

Comment: Are you using Git? Or TFVC? Why did you tag this as both TFS and Azure Dev Ops? Which are you actually using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a suggestion, which helped me in such a case.
(assuming there is no commit after the last push)

Open a git enabled bash and do these commands:

```
git stash
git checkout -b develop
git stash pop
git stash clear
```

- this will move all changes to the [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)
- create a new branch and checkout into it
- pull the changes from the stash
- clear the stash

Helpful [tutorial](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html).

Comment: I haven't committed anything yet.

Comment: @Markus Zeller. I tried to run git CMD, I got error "C:\Users\John>git stash
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: You need to cd into the root of your project directory.

Comment: The commands above will do the work. Just reopen VS and you are still checked out in the develop branch.

Comment: @Markus Zeller : Thank you so so much Sir.  Can you please direct me to a small quick tuto on VSTS please to read (links or ebook name on VSTS)?

Comment: This is from my **git** experience. I linked to the stash command above in the answer. From there you can read all the docs.

Comment: @Jane Then you got lucky it was uncommitted but....two weeks is an awful long time between commits. You should commit/push much more often so you're less likely to lose your work. I usually commit after writing a method or making a significant change to an existing method. That can mean multiple commits an hour.

Comment: @mason   yes you're right, 2 weeks is a lot !!! I've been told by my managers no to commit until they told me to do so. They just told me to do so today morning and when I looked at the branch I realized I was working on master page.

Comment: The help link you added is for git... not for vsts. I'm using vsts in vs 2017.

Comment: Under the hood **git** is used. Guess who owns github :D

Comment: No! Github is not git. Github is a webservice using git like Bitbucket oder Gitlab.